# ios Muliplayer strategy: Sending packets with ARC, (no structures)

Tags: objective-c, ios, game-center, multiplayer

I'm starting a multiplayer game, but the examples show passing a NSData object that was created using a structure.  With ARC though, I can't use C structures. (correct?) It seems that I'm supposed to use objects instead of C structures using ARC.  But how do I send NSData packets of objects?

I guess I could hard code a big byte array, but it seems like there should be an easier way.

Also, if it is possible to send an object, how do I send multiple objects and be able to differentiate between the ones I send?

Thanks!

Comment: today for networking I'd go for JSON encoded Strings instead of any binary stuff.. at least at the beginning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question was to use a NSKeyedArchiver.  It allows one to pack an object (or anything) into a NSData object.

Comment: The problem with this is that GameKit has a bug (as of today) that will occasionally stop receiving data with packet sizes > ~1000 bytes.  If you use NSKeyedArchiver, your packets will get to big, and you may stop receiving data and your code will stop working.

Answer (score 1):

ARC does not block you from using C structures, you just need to work a bit around the auto deallocation.

Also, if you want the quick and dirty way of handling it, you could disable ARC on your multiplayer manager, [using this method.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project)

Please describe which code you are following, and which ones are giving you problems.

Comment: I don't think I want to go about disabling ARC, as I'm new to objective-C, and haven't programmed without it.  Is there any way to work within the ARC system?

Comment: Fair enough, it was also a "quick and dirty" version. I have read the game-center documentation, and its fairly easy to convert to ARC. The tech demos given out at the WWDC2012 were arc as well, if you are a registered developer, you should have access to this.